# Xamarin Forms Custom Calendar

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a custom date picker, similar to that of iOS on my Xamarin Forms project, but I don't want to fire any event to get it open, it should load as soon as the page is on display. Can anyone help, please?[image]

Comment: use `OnAppearing`

Comment: No I want to create the whole thinng

Comment: "it should load as soon as the page is on display" - then use the page's `OnAppearing` event to call your calendar UI